# How to enter date and lookup field into an object

Tags: rest-api, custom-object, lookup, date

I rewrote the code, through anonymous works. 
I only have a problem with the date and field Log__c (lookup).

```
public class ExampleExchange {

@AuraEnabled
public static List<Exchange_Rate__c> getExchangeRate() {
    List<Exchange_Rate__c> conData = [SELECT ID, Name, Base_Currency__c, Date__c, CAD__c, EUR__c, GBP__c, USD__c, Log__c FROM Exchange_Rate__c];

    return conData;
}


@future(callout=true)
public static void saveRate() {

    Http http = new Http();

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    Log__c logResponse = new Log__c(

        Response_Body__c = response.getBody(),
        Status_Code__c = String.valueOf(response.getStatusCode())

    );
    insert logResponse;

    Map<String, Object> rootMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(logResponse.Response_Body__c);
    String base = String.valueOf(rootMap.get('base'));
    Date date = Date.valueOf(rootMap.get('date'));
    Map<String, Object> ratesMap = (Map<String, Object>) rootMap.get('rates');

    Exchange_Rate__c rate = new Exchange_Rate__c();

    rate.Base_Currency__c = base;
    rate.Date__c = date;
    rate.CAD__c = (Double) ratesMap.get('CAD');
    rate.EUR__c = (Double) ratesMap.get('EUR');
    rate.GBP__c = (Double) ratesMap.get('GBP');
    rate.USD__c = (Double) ratesMap.get('USD');


    insert rate;


}

}
```

In `"Date date = Date.valueOf(rootMap.get('date'));"`

> *Error: Static method cannot be referenced from a non static context: Date Date.valueOf(Object)*

How to write Log I do not understand.

Comment: Could you please [edit] to be specific about the issue you are having? Are you receiving an error, and if so what is it and on which line?

Comment: How are you able to save this class? You can not use a reserved `date` keyword. You should receive a compile error `Identifier name is reserved: date`. After renaming the attribute, i was able to save this class. How to reproduce the error? Because this code works for me,

Comment: I cheated, but he returned my old mistake  "Invalid date: 2020-03-04"

Comment: Answer: String dates = String.valueOf(rootMap.get('date'));
Date d = date.valueOf(dates);

Answer (score 1):

It seems that data type of `Status_Code__c`  in `Log__c` is `TEXT`

Try below piece of code

```
Log__c logResponse = new Log__c(

            Response_Body__c = response.getBody(),
            Status_Code__c = String.valueOf(response.getStatusCode())

        );
 insert logResponse;
```

If this does not help, please post data type of `Response_Body__c`  and `Status_Code__c`

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But I'm not sure if it will enter data into the object.

Comment: It should enter the data. If it does not, then post your error here.

Comment: There are no errors, but no data is added.

Comment: What is the response received??

Comment: Nothing. {"rates":{"CAD":1.7297075544,"EUR":1.1721268241,"USD":1.2866436148,"GBP":1.0},"base":"GBP","date":"2020-02-28"} This is a request, but it has not been recorded.

Comment: If there is no response, then you have to check the Service and handle the log creation accordingly.